# Statistical Mechanics: Particles on a Sphere

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics, pressure, partition-function

$K$ identical particles of mass $m_0$ are bound to move on a sphere of radius R. The system is at equilibrium at temperature $T_0$.

1 - What's the internal energy ($E$)?

2 - What's the specific heat at constant volume ($c_v$)? And what's the pressure ($P$) exerted by the gas onto the sphere?

First of all we're dealing with a 2D gas, and this is something totally new to me. Here is my effort.

1 - The internal energy should be given by $$E=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \log{Z}$$ where $Z$ is the partition function and $\beta=k_bT_0$. We need therefore the partition function. With reference to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136966/calculation-of-the-partition-function-for-a-classical-2d-gas-lying-on-the-surfac), our hamiltonian should be: $$H(x,y,z,p_{x},p_{y},p_z)=\frac{1}{2m}\left(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}\right)\to \frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{p_{\theta}^{2}}{R^{2}}+\frac{p_{\phi}^{2}}{R^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}\right)$$ and the partition function *per particle*: $$z=\int \exp\left[-\frac{\beta}{2m}\left(\frac{p_{\theta}^{2}}{R^{2}}+\frac{p_{\phi}^{2}}{R^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}\right)\right] d\theta d\phi dp_{\theta}dp_{\phi} \qquad$$
At this point the complexive partition function should be: $$Z=\frac{z^K}{K!}$$
Finally we could apply $$E=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \log{Z}$$ but I have no clue how to deal with this in practice, nor am I sure all this is correct.

2 - Once we have the internal energy, unless I'm mistaken the specific heat should be given by $$c_v=\frac{\partial E}{\partial T_0}$$
Finally, what about the pressure? I think it should be given by $P=k_BT_0 \rho $, with $ \rho $ density of the gas. Am I right? However, how do I calculate the pressure in 2D? It makes no physical sense to me, to be honest.

Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: Looks correct except that in the partition function you need to integrate over the positions too. It should be clear over which range.

Comment: Have you learned about the equipartition theorem yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach for part 1 looks correct. It should just be a matter of working through the details of the algebra. Similarly you have the correct formula for the heat capacity.

The pressure on the sphere is the pressure pushing in, trying to make it smaller, so it is related to the change in free energy with the radius. In general the pressure of a gas is given by
$$P = -\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_T$$
Where $F = k_BT\ln Z$ is the free energy. Now in your case $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$ and you are interested in the pressure *on the sphere*, rather than the pressure *of the gas*, (i.e. a large pressure should make $V$ smaller, not bigger) so there will be an extra minus sign. I will let you work out the details